# Bluetooth PIN code for Apple Pencil

Tags: bluetooth, apple-pencil

I need to pair with an Apple Pencil; yet I cannot seem to be able to determine the correct PIN for the device. What is the default PIN for an Apple Pencil Version One?

[image]

Comment: What do you need a PIN for?

Comment: A Bluetooth PIN allows a device to pair with another Bluetooth device. Sorry I was not explicit enough. @nohillside

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear either. When you pair your Pencil with your iPad, when/how are you getting asked for a PIN?

Comment: @nohillside All I need is the pin.

Comment: The Apple Pencil is only compatible with iPad, not with iPhone, that's why you may not be able to pair it, see https://www.apple.com/shop/select-apple-pencil.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. I don't understand what you are trying to do. iPad should not ask for a PIN. If you try to connect the pencil to a non-supported device then it may make sense. I guess Apple Pencil is generating a PIN and it's transferred using the lightning connector, in that case, you need to figure out a way to retrieve it. Apple Pencil may also not require a PIN, then you need to tell the host to use Apple Pencil as an input device. Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to do and we can help you with a different solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have the iPad PRO 10.5” and Apple Pencil gen 1 (which is compatible with this model iPad).
Somehow some of the lightning pins of my iPad burned and I was no longer able to pair the Apple Pencil.

Here’s what I did:
with the pencil charging threw cable I used the app Wunderfind on the iPad to find the Bluetooth connection of the Apple Pen, pressed connect and then it asked me for a code (exactly like in your pic), I put **1234** and it worked! Now my Apple Pen is paired again without using the lightning port!
I don’t know if mine was just luck but you can try this.

Comment: I came to this page because I had the same issue. My pencil lost connection to the ipad, so I used a Bluetooth app BT Inspector, which found it, but requested a pin. 1234 worked. Big thanks to Giulia! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pair an Apple Pencil with an iPhone, they only work with iPads (and don't need a PIN to pair them. The first model of the Pencil actually pairs by having it plug into the iPad so the pairing isn't even bluetooth-based)

Comment: I’m glad you had the opportunity to reiterate the obvious, but I didn’t ask if it is compatible. I asked for the pairing pin.

Comment: @nope There is no PIN. And even if you could somehow pair an Apple Pencil with your iPhone it wouldn't do anything because iPhones lack the required hardware in the screen (and most probably also the software).

Comment: Again, thank you for your input; but I am not looking for any of the information you have provided. The fact that the PIN is automatic with the iPad does not change the fact that the pencil itself is requesting the PIN you say doesn’t exist. The fact that it is not compatible, not designed for, et cetera; is not my concern.

Comment: @nope It's iOS which is requesting a PIN here, something it does for all Bluetooth-based input devices it tries to pair to.

Comment: So... what’s the pin?

Comment: @nope There is no PIN, 1st gen Pencils don't even pair via Bluetooth (you need to plug them into the iPad to pair the two).

Comment: ‍♂️ Then why do I have this dialogue: enter code

Comment: I understand you say it can’t be done because proprietary blah blah blah but all I need is the pin

Comment: @nope You have the dialog because the iPhone doesn't know anything about Pencils and just displays the standard BT pairing dialogue.

Comment: If you don’t have the information requested I don’t understand why you keep answering

Comment: @nope You are asking for something which doesn't exist, to pair two devices which can't work together. Let's see whether somebody has a better answer.